# Understanding Wedge Products in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $F$ vector space, $u\in End(V)$, and $M$ the matrix of $u$ wit respect to a basis $Q$. Let $\widetilde{u}\in End(V)$ be the endomorphism whose matrix with respect to the basis $\mathcal{A}$ is equal to $adj(M)$ (the adjugate of $M$). Prove that:

For every $\beta,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\in V$,
$$
\widetilde{u}(\beta) \wedge \alpha_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_n
= \beta \wedge u(\alpha_2) \wedge \dots \wedge u(\alpha_n).
$$

I know I can represent the linear transformation of the adjugate as
$$\langle u(v), v\rangle = \langle v, \widetilde{u}(v) \rangle $$
and the wedge product by definition is
$$ u \wedge v = u \otimes v - v \otimes u $$
But how do I use that representation to prove the equation above?

**Attempt:** Let try with just the wedge of $\widetilde{u}(\beta)$ and $\alpha_2$. So
$$
\widetilde{u}(\beta) \wedge \alpha_2 
= \widetilde{u}(\beta) \otimes \alpha_2 - \alpha_2 \otimes \widetilde{u}(\beta)
= \beta \otimes u(\alpha_2) - u(\alpha_2) \otimes \beta
= \beta \wedge u(\alpha_2)
$$
Is this correct or do I have to provide more details? Can I just generalize this for $n$-wegdes?

Comment: There's another notion of $adj(M)$ regarding determinant and principal minors. Are you sure it's not about that one? Also, $u\land v$ is rather the coset of $u\times v$ in the quotient $V\otimes V/I$ where $I$ is generated by the elements $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$.

Comment: @Berci I just added editted by post to include that

Comment: Did you consider use geometric algebra?

Comment: I don't know any geometric algebra. :(

Comment: @ErdelvonMises If you have some beginner guides, I look at them

Comment: @Berci Many of us often work with the embedding of $\Lambda^k V$ in $\otimes^k V$ as the completely skew-symmetric tensors, rather than with the quotient.

Comment: Nevertheless, the *adjugate matrix* is different from the *adjoint*, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix .

Comment: @berci Can I get any feedback to what I have done above?

Comment: Why would $\tilde u(\beta)\otimes\alpha=\beta\otimes u(\alpha)$? What is the dimension of $\Lambda^n V$?

Comment: @berci Is it because $adj(M^*)=adj(M)^*?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'? No need for transpose and inner product in this exercise.

Comment: @berci It has the equation in your question. So what I did it right or wrong?

Comment: Since you're using the wrong notion (adjoint instead of adjugate matrix), it's basically all wrong. Do you know the connection between determinant and $\Lambda^nV$?

Comment: @berci Then how is the right way to prove this statement?

Comment: I gave you some hints in my answer. Comment below that for any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

The [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) is different from the *adjoint*, its definition doesn't require inner product (which btw doesn't exist over arbitrary fields).

Let $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ be a basis of $V$.
Then for any indices $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, the outer product $e_{a_1}\land e_{a_2}\land\dots\land e_{a_n}$ is either zero (if $a_i=a_j$ for some $i\ne j$) or it's (perhaps the negative of) $e_1\land e_2\land\dots\land e_n$, repeatedly using $e_i\land e_j = -e_j\land e_i$ to permute the indices.

So, the single outer product ${\bf e}:=e_1\land e_2\land\dots\land e_n$ is a basis of $\Lambda^nV$, which is thus one dimensional.

**Hints** for further steps:

1. it's enough to prove the statement for $\beta,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\in\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ because by (multi-)linearity the general case follows.
2. $\tilde u(e_i)$ gives the $i$th column of the matrix of $\tilde u$.
3. Use determinant and [Laplace expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

Comment: Since (1)  given by the definition of $\widetilde{u}$? I understand (2). But I can't seem to understand how to start with $\widetilde{u}(\beta) \wedge \alpha_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_n$